# jQuery - Find Value of a Checkbox in a Table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following html:

[image]

When I click on the Save Schedule button, I need to navigate up, then down, to the checkbox input and see if it is checked or not,preferably using JQUERY. I've tried various combinations of closest, parent, etc, but can't figure it out.
EDIT:

I have this set up in a Kendo grid as:

```
 columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Save").Text("<span class=\"k- 
 icon k-i-check\"></span>Save 
Schedule").Click("saveSchedules")).Width(80).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = 
"text-center" });
```

My saveSchedules function is

```
 function saveSchedules(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = $(e).parent('tr').find('.enabled-checkbox').prop('checked');

/// etc
```

How do I do this in the function?

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image of text.

Comment: `$button.parent('tr').find('.enabled-checkbox').prop('checked')` supposing there is no other checkbox of this class in the row.

Comment: Thanks! Please see EDIT for how to do this in my function.

Comment: @Scott, `e` is an event, you need to start from `$(e.currentTarget)`, which is the control clicked.

Comment: I use var dataItem = $(e.currentTarget).parent('tr').find('.enabled-checkbox').prop('checked'); now. If I log dataItem to console I get "undefined".

Comment: @Scott right, you need `closest` instead of `parent`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```js
$('a').on('click', (e) => {
  let v = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr').find('.enabled-checkbox').prop('checked')
  console.log(v)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>TD1</td>
    <td>TD2</td>
    <td>
      <span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="enabled-checkbox" />
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>TD4</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I use $(e.currentTarget).parent('tr').find('.enabled-checkbox') WITHOUT .prop, I get the checkbox. With it, I get undefined.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to closest as suggested by Zorgo above.